# change style of mutiple div id's

Tags: jquery

I need help with changing every img element with the id "playerSprite".
On a keypress event, all elements with the playersprite id need to subtract 16px from the top style.

Code:

```
if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
    document.getElementById("playerSprite")style.top -16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="images/test.png" id="playerSprite" style="position: absolute; top: 136px; left: -176px;">
<img src="images/test2.png" id="playerSprite" style="position: absolute; top: 136px; left: -176px;">
```

How to get this working?

Comment: Not possible.Id's must be unique. You'll have to use class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery. this should work.

```
if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
    $("img").css("top","-16px");
}
```

edit: you cant have multiple images with same ID, so if you need a certain selection of images, give them the same class and change "img" to ".class"

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you a refacor. Give a class playerSprite to your images (id must be unique) then

```
   $(".playerSprite").each(
        function(i,elem) { 
          // to get top value use $(elem).css('top');
          $(elem).css('top','yourValue + px') 
    });
```

html

```
<img src="images/test.png" id="playerSprite1" class="playerSprite" style="position: absolute; top: 136px; left: -176px;">
<img src="images/test2.png" id="playerSprite2" class="playerSprite" style="position: absolute; top: 136px; left: -176px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the IDs "playerSprite" to classes, then change the JS to get the images by class and create a loop for each image:

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('playerSprite');

for (var i = 0, ii = elements.length; i < ii; i++) {
    elements[i].style.top = (parseInt(elements[i].style.top) - 16) + 'px';
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/SL8LA/

Comment: this works, awesome! but how to substract -16px not set it to 16px?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of the question... (Thought you wanted to set it to -16px.) Have changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

id's need to be unique. use a class name instead.

like so:
els = document.getElementsByClassName("playerSprite");

then have to loop over all the elements and set the style.

loop els: <-- could use a for loop
els[i].style.top = '26px';

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, id's should really by unique, you probalbly want to use classes instead of id's.

So let's assume the classname you use is `player-sprite` and you are using a modern version of jQuery (1.6). Then you could do this:

```
$('img.player-sprite').css('top', '-=16');
```

see http://api.jquery.com/css/